# Which is the most common question with "sound": Do you hear the sound?; What makes the sound?; What is that sound?; What sound is it? What sounds?

Tags: phrase-request, questions, phrase-choice

Say, you suddenly hear a sound,

Which is the **most common** question to ask?:

> a) Do you hear the sound?
>   b) What makes the sound?
>   c) What is that sound?
>   d) What sound is it?
>   e) What sounds?

According to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Do%20you%20hear%20the%20sound%2C%20What%20makes%20the%20sound%2C%20What%20is%20that%20sound%2C%20What%20sound%20is%20it%2C%20What%20sounds&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CDo%20you%20hear%20the%20sound%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWhat%20makes%20the%20sound%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWhat%20is%20that%20sound%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWhat%20sound%20is%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWhat%20sounds%3B%2Cc0), **What sounds** and **What is that sound?** (dark green and light green lines respectively)  seem to be the most common forms.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, the following four would definitely be among the most common ways to say that and they probably would be at the very top of the list:

> Did you hear that?
>
> What was that?
>
> What's that sound?
>
> What's that noise?

Comment: can we change "What's that noise" to "What's that sound?" are they the same?

Comment: Yes, they're basically the same.